# How to use gRPC with golang echo framework?

Tags: echo, grpc-go

I am trying to perform inter-service communication between microservices. I followed the [documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/) and it was successful. Then, I tried to establish the same with [echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) framework. But that gives me an invalid memory address when trying to call the gRPC registered method.

```
 rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closedpanic: 
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference 
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7eacad]
```

Server config:

```
    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    hellopb.RegisterHelloServiceServer(s, NewServer())

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, echo.Map{"status": "success"})
    })
    s.Serve(e.Listener)
```

Client panics:

```
    resp, err := client.Hello(context.Background(), request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
```

`Hello` is the function registered with gRPC.

Comment: please provide more details, like the panic stack or part of the code. This error does not look to be related to the framework.

Comment: Does it work fine if you replace the echo listener by a basic tcp listener (e.g. net.Listener) ?

Comment: In that case, http and gRPC server is not able to run on same port simultaneously.

Comment: yeah, I know. I was wondering if the `Echo` listener is affecting the gRPC communication.